# Enhance java classes using traits, how to declare inside trait the java fields?

Tags: scala, traits

My goal is to enhance inside scala code an existing Java class using a trait mix-in. For example to add a method like java.awt.Rectangle.translate(dx, dy) to java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D class. For this I create the following trait:

```
trait RectangleLike {
  var x: Double  // abstract vals to correspond to java class fields
  var y: Double  //   I need these vars to refer to them inside translate method
  def translate(dx: Double, dy: Double) {
    x = x + dx
    y = y + dy
  }
  // more concrete trait methods here
} // defines without errors in scala REPL
```

Then use the trait when constructing an Ellipse:

```
val egg = new java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D.Double(5, 10, 20, 30) with RectangleLike
```

However when I execute the above script in scala REPL I get the following output:

```
<console>:8: error: overriding variable x in trait RectangleLike of type Double;
variable x in class Double of type Double has incompatible type;
other members with override errors are: y
val egg = new java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D.Double(5, 10, 20, 30) with RectangleLike
```

I suspect that this error is due to the way Scala implements vars - as a private field and a getter/setter pair of methods. Is what I try to achieve doable? Is there another way to define the java class fields in the trait and then refer to them inside the concrete trait methods?

Thanks in advance
Jack Dimas

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it is doable but instead of trying to access the private fields of the classes you want to mix in with (which is most likely a bad idea anyway), you would want to declare the self-type of `RectangleLike` to be `java.awt.geom.RectangularShape` so that you can use your trait with e.g. `Ellipse2D.Double` just as well as with `Rectangle2D.Double`.

Here is how it works:

```
trait RectangleLike {
  self: java.awt.geom.RectangularShape =>

  def translate(dx: Double, dy: Double) {
    setFrame(getX + dx, getY + dy, getX + getWidth, getY + getHeight)
  }
}

object Test {
  val foo = new java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D.Double with RectangleLike
}
```

By saying `self: java.awt.geom.RectangularShape =>` you declare the self-type of your trait which enables you to access all corresponding methods like the necessary getters and setters, allows for using your trait with all descendants of `RectangularShape`, and also "restricts" your trait so that it can only be used as a mixin to classes which themselves are subtypes of `RectangularShape`.

The **alternative** to the above scenario is using a so-called *view* of your `RectangularShape` which is a common paradigm as well. For this, you would e.g. declare a class

```
class RichRectangularShape(shape: java.awt.geom.RectangularShape) {
  def translate(dx: Double, dy: Double) {
    shape.setFrame(shape.getX + dx, shape.getY + dy,
                   shape.getX + shape.getWidth, shape.getY + shape.getHeight)
  }
}
```

Scala has a way of *implicitly viewing* an object of one type as an object of another type. If you happen to call a method on a object which is not declared in its corresponding type, the compiler trys to find a type that provides this method and in particular also trys to find an implicit conversion so that your original object can be viewed as an instance of the latter type. For this to work, you would typically declare the companion object of `RichRectangularShape` as something like this:

```
object RichRectangularShape {
  implicit def mkRRS(shape: java.awt.geom.RectangularShape): RichRectangularShape =
    new RichRectangularShape(shape)
}
```

Then:

```
scala> import RichRectangularShape._
import RichRectangularShape._

scala> val foo = new java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D.Double
foo: java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D.Double = java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D$Double@0

scala> foo.translate(5,2)

scala> foo.getX
res1: Double = 5.0

scala> foo.getY
res2: Double = 2.0

scala> :t foo
java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D.Double
```

Comment: @forNelton impressive! Thanks a mil I really was stuck on this. I have to study implicit views.

Comment: You're welcome. Depending on the type of your application I think the first approach might be more appropriate as the method calls are likely to be way faster without all the implicit hassle.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed impressive explanation and example!

I have one little problem with this approach, the `translate` method includes the real calculation that I would like to avoid. Yes in this case it is very simple but generally speaking such method may be complicated and lead to the serious development. Therefore I suggest the following approach:

```
trait RectangleLike extends java.awt.geom.RectangularShape {
    def translate(dx: Int, dy: Int): Unit = {
        val rect = new java.awt.Rectangle
        rect.setRect(getX, getY, getWidth, getHeight)
        rect.translate(dx,dy)
        setFrame(rect.getX, rect.getY, rect.getWidth, rect.getHeight)
      }
}
```

In this way I am using the original `translate` calculation.